# For any element of Archimedean ordered field there is a greater natural number

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ordered-fields

Let $F=(X,+_X,*_X,\le_X)$ be a totally ordered field. Let $\mathbb N'$ be the isomorphic copy of natural numbers in it defined by the function $\phi:\mathbb N \rightarrow X$ such that $\phi(n)=1_X\underbrace{+_X...+_X}_{n\,times\,+}1_X$.

Let $F$ be Archimedean, i.e. $\forall x \in X\setminus{\{0_X}\}:\exists n \in \mathbb N':n|x|>1$.

How to prove that $\forall x \in X:\exists n \in \mathbb N':n>x$?

Comment: Case distinction, $x < 0$, $x = 0$, and $x > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x>0$ then $x^{-1}\in X$ and $x^{-1}>0$ (Can you see why?). Therefore by the Archimedean property there is a $n$ s.t. $nx^{-1}>1$, thuse $n>x$.